# Rails upgrade from 4.2.0 to 5.1.2 causes the following coffeescript code to break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, haml

So the coffeescript code shown in the attached view runs without a problem in my Rails 4.2.0 view, but is breaking in the Rails 5.1.2 upgrade with the messages shown:  I have upgraded the gems shown below:

```
coffee-rails from 4.1.0 to 4.2.2
coffee-script-source from 1.9.0 to 1.12.2
```

And the haml_coffee_assets has always pointed to the master branch as shown below so no changes there:

```
gem 'haml_coffee_assets', git: "https://github.com/netzpirat/haml_coffee_assets"
```

Before I start to make crazy changes, I want to see if anyone else has run into similar problems.  I am moving away from coffeescript in favor of the plain javascript in my newer Rails applications and have no problems with embedded javascript code.  However, this is an older application that is not used heavily and I want to invest minimum time in maintaining it.  There is too much Coffeescript code in it for me to convert it easily.  If there is a site that will let me convert the coffeescript to Javascript without too many problems, then I would like to.  The best solution would be to just keep going forward with what I have.

[image: coffeescript compile error]

Has anyone run into this problem?  Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
- if @well.has_sense_graph?
  #sensitivity.tab
    = render :partial => "shared_wells/show_sensitivity", :locals => {:sensitivity => sense_hash[:sensitivity], :offset => sense_hash[:offset] }
    %br
    #discount_chart

:coffeescript
  $ ->
    model = new Backbone.Model
      forecastTickInterval: #{graph_hash[:forecast_tick_interval]}
      typeWell: #{@well.to_json}
      x_labels: #{graph_hash[:price_array]}
      disc_rate_array: #{graph_hash[:disc_rate_array]}
      disc_pv10_array: #{graph_hash[:disc_pv10_array]}
      ngl_array: #{ngl_vol_array}
    view = new VGStream.Views.TypeWells.Show(
      model: model
    ).render()
    VGStream.App.router = new VGStream.Routers.Tabs()
    VGStream.App.currentView = view
    Backbone.history.start()
    _.defer ->
      $(document).scrollTop(0)
```

Comment: Can you post the coffeescript code being executed?

Comment: Please post the code not an image

Comment: Does `render :partial => "shared_wells/show_sensitivity"` render coffescript? Otherwise you need to escape it.

Comment: @max.  No it does not render coffeescript, only haml.  But the current code exactly as shown works great in Rails 4.2.0.  I haven't made any code changes whatsoever, only the Gem upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this problem in a practical way.  Given the goal that I have to get rid of CoffeeScript code in my application and replace it with equivalent Javascript code, I did the following:

All pages where I have embedded CoffeeScript code in the haml pages as shown above in the code that I have provided, I replaced it with equivalent Javascript code as shown below:

```
:javascript

   $(function() {
     ...
   });
```

Note that I left the 'pure' coffeescript files, i.e., with extension '.coffee' stored in assets/javascript/... ' folders alone, since my more immediate goal is to get the Rails 5.1.2 upgrade done as quickly as possible.

For some reason that I do not know (nor do I care to know), the embedded coffeescript code no longer works for me as it did in the Rails 4.2.0 version.  But since I do not care about CoffeeScript anymore, this hybrid solution is acceptable to me.